# First Django cron with Celery

Tags: python, django, cron, celery, django-celery

I read lot of documentations about `Celery` with `Django` and I tried to create my first `cron task`.

**Objective :**

This task should be able to execute a function which clean a specific table each day at 11:30 am

**My code :**

All seems to be good, I see the task in Celery but nothing change.

I have in my ***base.py*** file :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ....
    'django_cron',
)

CRON_CLASSES = [
    "app.cron.cron.DeleteOldToken",
]

CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = False
CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED = True
# Add a one-minute timeout to all Celery tasks.
CELERYD_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT = 60
```

I have a ***celery.py*** file :

```
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'main.settings.base')

app = Celery('main')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

I have a ***cron.py*** file :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django_cron import CronJobBase, Schedule

from ..tasks import delete_old_token

class DeleteOldToken(CronJobBase):
    RUN_AT_TIMES = ['11:30']

    schedule = Schedule(run_at_times=RUN_AT_TIMES)
    code = 'app.delete_old_token'

    def do(self):
        delete_old_token()
```

And the file ***tasks.py*** :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import datetime
from datetime import datetime

from celery import shared_task, task
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from django.conf import settings
from token_jwt.models import UserToken

@task()
def delete_old_token(self):
    for token in UserToken.objects.exclude(date_information__isnull=True):
        tdi = token.date_information
        if datetime(tdi.year, tdi.month, tdi.day) < datetime.now() + relativedelta(months=2):
            token.delete()
```

**Command :**

Then I tried to launch this command :

```
celery -A main worker --loglevel=info
```

It displays :

```
 -------------- celery@pydev-jungbluth v4.2.1 (windowlicker)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Linux-4.15.0-45-generic-x86_64-with-debian-buster-sid 2019-02-08 11:29:10
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         main:0x7fd4befe5cf8
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379//
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost:6379/
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . app.tasks.delete_old_token

[2019-02-08 11:29:10,889: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379//
[2019-02-08 11:29:10,894: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2019-02-08 11:29:11,914: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2019-02-08 11:29:11,920: INFO/MainProcess] celery@pydev-jungbluth ready.
```

But nothing appears. It seems that my cron task doesn't work or doesn't be executed.

Do you have any idea ?

**EDIT:**

Celery beat gives me :

```
$ celery -A main beat
celery beat v4.2.1 (windowlicker) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
LocalTime -> 2019-02-08 12:03:22
Configuration ->
    . broker -> redis://localhost:6379//
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%WARNING
    . maxinterval -> 5.00 minutes (300s)
```

Comment: Run `beat` it checks that which task time is to be executed.

Comment: `$ celery -A proj beat` Run celery beat

Comment: I added edit part with `celery beat`

Answer (score 1):

`django-cron` does not interface with `celery`.  IF you want celery to run a job at a scheduled time, you want to use [`django-celery-beat`](https://pypi.org/project/django_celery_beat/).   Django celery beat will let you set up your schedule of cron jobs via the django admin panel.  When you use it, you'll have to modify your celery beat to start with the following option:

```
--scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler
```

The full setup steps can be seen [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#using-custom-scheduler-classes).